# MongoDB, retrieve specific field in array of objects

Tags: mongodb, meteor

In my collection I have an array of objects. I'd like to share only a subset of those objects, but I can't find out how to do this?

Here are a few things I tried:

```
db.collections.find({},
  { fields: {
    'myField': 1, // works
    'myArray': 1, // works
    'myArray.$': 1, // doesn't work
    'myArray.$.myNestedField': 1, // doesn't work
    'myArray.0.myNestedField': 1, // doesn't work
  }
};
```

Comment: Did you try `'myArray.myNestedField':1` ?

Comment: That's absolutely correct! Didn't make sense to me to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myArray.myNestedField':1 for projecting nested fields from the array.
```

I'll briefly explain all the variants you have.

```
'myField': 1 -- Projecting a field value
'myArray': 1 -- Projecting a array as a whole - (Can be scalar, embedded and sub document)
```

The below variants works only with [`positional operator($)`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) in the query preceding the projections and projects only the first element matching the query.

```
'myArray.$': 1
'myArray.$.myNestedField': 1
```

This is not a valid projection operation.

```
'myArray.0.myNestedField': 1
```

More here on how to [`query`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/) & [`project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/) documents